# How to reset mouse rotation in Java3D?

Tags: java-3d

I am writing a Java Applet sing Java3D and would like to reset the rotation of mouse in MouseRotate behavior when a button is clicked. The relevant codes are as follows:

```
BoundingSphere bound =
            new BoundingSphere(new Point3d(0.0,0.0,0.0), 100.0);    

        MouseRotate mouseRotate = new MouseRotate();
                    TransformGroup modelGroup = new TransformGroup();
                    mouseRotate.setTransformGroup(modelGroup);  
                    modelGroup.addChild(mouseRotate);
                    mouseRotate.setSchedulingBounds(bound);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. It seems there is no way to reset `MouseRotate` without rewriting it.

Second try: Include another `TransformGroup` as parent of the `modelGroup` into the scene graph and set its transform to the invert transform of the `modelGroup` when resetting is denied.

```
TransformGroup modelGroupReset = new TransformGroup();
TransformGroup modelGroup = new TransformGroup();
modelGroupReset.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
modelGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
modelGroupReset.addChild(modelGroup);

JButton resetButton = new JButton();
resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Transform3D t3d = new Transform3D();
        modelGroup.getTransform(t3d);
        t3d.invert();
        modelGroupReset.setTransform(t3d);
    }
});
```

;

Answer (score 2):

It works. Thanks a lot! However while implementing your proposed method, accidentally I found a simpler. The code comes bellow.
This method seems to be working for my purpose and there is no need for the parent TransformGrop either. The method is obvious and I thought I tried it before. Perhaps I did try this but for other reasons it didn't work. Cheers, Hassan

```
TransformGroup modelGroup = new TransformGroup();
modelGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);
modelGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);

JButton resetButton = new JButton();
resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    modelGroup.setTransform( new Transform3D());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try: Recall `mouseRotate.setTransformGroup(modelGroup);` followed by `mouseRotate.initialize();`. Not tested!

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. Whenever I use initialize() method, I get the following error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: wakeupOn must be called from initialize or processStimulus